# Questioning the dynamicity of Spacers in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have heard from multiple places that spacers are meant to be dynamic/relative to different screen sizes. I have been using them as an important piece to my layout but they have let me down. Can someone show me if I'm using them incorrectly? Here is an example of a rectangle with an HStack of squares across it. Since the rectangle starts out big and I also need to push it down to the screen I use a lot of spacers(which seem unnecessary). I have tried using padding but it doesn't push it down as much as I need. After the code I've provided you'll see two pictures. One is of an iPod touch(7th generation) and the other of an iPhone 12 Pro Max. The layout doesn't match at all across devices. My goal is for both devices to have the layout porportions that the iPod touch has.

```
ZStack {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1..<38)  { _ in
                Spacer()
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
        }
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Rectangle()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Rectangle()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Rectangle()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Rectangle()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

[image: iPod touch]
[image: Iphone 12 Pro Max]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need multiple `Spacer()`

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<5) {_ in
                    Rectangle()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
    }
}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
If you know the size of the view with blue background which I made it as relative to 40% of screen height for now and then `Spacer()` will fill up the rest of the screen with space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to mark this question right because it was the first one given and I like the method it uses but both questions reach what was intended. But I'm also wondering why what I used didn't work. I was only using spacers which are relative to screen sizes so it would seem that it would turn out that way. Do you have any idea why it didn't?

Comment: When I said "turn out that way" I meant why didn't it have the same result on both screens.

Comment: @Chr0mePl8edSt0vePipe You had two `VStack` in the `ZStack` overlaying each other and has a different layout which also can be different on different screen sizes. `Spacer` will make space according to screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't exactly clear what you want the layout to be like. So this code is based on what I speculate about your question, I don't really understand it.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LayoutView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      VStack {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.white)
        ZStack {
          Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
          VStack {
            HStack {
              Rectangle().scaledToFit()
              Rectangle().scaledToFit()
              Rectangle().scaledToFit()
              Rectangle().scaledToFit()
              Rectangle().scaledToFit()
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: 50)
            Spacer()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct LayoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    LayoutView()
      .previewDevice(.some(.init(rawValue: "iPhone 12 Pro Max")))
    LayoutView()
      .previewDevice(.some(.init(rawValue: "iPod touch (7th generation)")))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the above correct because both answers reached the intended goal (sorry for not making it too clear) and because the other answer was given first and I just preferred the above code.

Comment: I also think @andykkt 's answer is better. `.padding(.vertical)` maybe more useful.